# converting string to network address

Tags: string, ip-address

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application where I would like to convert an IP address from a wide-character string in dotted-quad notation to an address (similar to `inet_aton`);

I'm doing this:

```
DWORD StringToAddress( const std::wstring& address )
{
    BYTE a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
    swscanf( address.c_str(), L"%u.%u.%u.%u", &a, &b, &c, &d );
    return d << 24 | c << 16 | b << 8 | a;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I give an address like `169.254.255.255` the third quad comes out of the `swscanf` as `0` and not `255`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a good way to fix this?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has [inet_addr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738563.aspx), but it does not seem to support `UNICODE`:

```
#include <winsock2.h>

std::string address = "169.254.255.255";
unsigned long ip = inet_addr(address.c_str());
```

Comment: I'll probably end up doing that. But I am curious as to why my `swscanf` isn't working right.

Comment: @PaulH, probably because `%u` returns a `unsigned int` value that's larger than a byte. Try declaring `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` as `UINT` instead and mask their low byte in your last line.